# How to make field key unique which does not have name in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

My json to create a record in mongodb is as follows:

```
{
    'timestamp': {
        'elasticsearch': {
            'backup_status': 'string',
            'backup_folder': 'string',
        },
        'mongodb': {
            'backup_status': 'string',
            'backup_folder': 'string',
        },
        'postgresdb': {
            'backup_status': 'string',
            'backup_folder': 'string',
        },
        'overall_backup_status': 'string',
    },
};
```

Here the key "timestamp" holds a different value each time, I would like to make this field unique. I have tried check various documentations where I see examples on how to make a field unique by its name but here the field I need to make unique does not have name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to preserve uniqueness in key names, What I suggest is you maintain an additional fields that will contain those key names, then you can build a unique index on it.

for example your object should look like this:

```
{
    unique_keys = [ 'elasticsearch.backup_status', 'elasticsearch.backup_folder'],
    'timestamp': {
        'elasticsearch': {
            'backup_status': 'string',
            'backup_folder': 'string',
        },
    },
};
```

On every update you need to maintain the `unique_keys` field accordingly. Now you can build a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on `unique_keys`, this will protect you from having duplicates as required.